# How do I separate the geom_label_repel in the geom_bar?

Tags: ggplot2, label, ggrepel

[image]

I want to pull away these overlapping labels in ggplot.

I am seeking for help to pull away each label to avoid overlapping. I've tried modify `box.padding`, `max.overlaps`, `min.segment.length` but still faild.

```
data = read.csv("995_matched_cancer_types.csv", header=T)
names(data) <- c("cancer_types","primary_disease","cell_lines")
data <- subset(data, data$primary_disease!="Unknown")
data["counts"] <- data$cell_lines/sum(data$cell_lines)
data["info"] <- paste0(data$cancer_types,"(",data$cell_lines,")")


ggplot(data, aes(x=1, y=counts, label=info, fill=cancer_types)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge2(), color="black") +
  geom_text_repel(position=position_dodge2(.9), 
                  box.padding = .5,
                  max.overlaps = 30,
                  min.segment.length = 0,
                  ylim = c(.03,Inf)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL)+
  theme_classic() + theme(axis.line.x = element_blank(),
                          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                          axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
                          strip.text = element_text(size = 12),
                          legend.position = "none"
                          )+
  facet_wrap(~primary_disease)
```

If someone would help me with this problem, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Could you please share the "995_matched_cancer_types.csv" file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZNeoGXy_QtUSTQE-tCWBOrYhn7117nI-/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I have changed `ylim = c(.03,Inf)` to `ylim = c(NA,Inf)`. This removes most of the overlaps. You can play around with the `xlim` and `ylim` values (in my opinion). You can try different `height` and `width` parameters of the `ggsave` function as well.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=1, y=counts, label=info, fill=cancer_types)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge2(), color="black") +
  geom_text_repel(position=position_dodge2(.9), 
                  box.padding = 0.5,
                  max.overlaps = 30,
                  min.segment.length = 0,
                  ylim = c(NA,Inf)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL)+
  theme_classic() + theme(axis.line.x = element_blank(),
                          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                          axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
                          strip.text = element_text(size = 12),
                          legend.position = "none"
  )+
  facet_wrap(~primary_disease)

# save plot as png
ggsave("fig.png",
       width = 20,
       height = 10,
       units = "in"
      )
```

[image]